# Firefox: navigator.clipboard.readText is not a function

Tags: firefox, clipboard

We have `paste-on-right-click` functionality built on top of xtermjs, which works nicely in Chrome and Edge, however I was notified today that it fails in Firefox. I was surprised. According to [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText#browser_compatibility) on MDN, `readText()` should be supported, and moreover, it should be seamless (with no permission prompt) for same origin content.

[image]

However when I inspect `navigator.clipboard` instance on the console, it doesn't contain `readText` method at all. Any ideas? Is it even possible to programmatically read from the Clipboard in Firefox?

[image]